# Odd class member syntax shown in ILSpy

Tags: c#, syntax, destructor, ilspy

I'm poking around a few dlls within the XNA framework using [ILSpy](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ILSpy.ashx) and came across this:

```
class KerningHelper
{
    private void !KerningHelper()
    {
        ((IDisposable)this).Dispose();
    }
}
```

**What is the exclamation mark for in the above?** Is it an issue with ILSpy, or something else?

Note, the class has a separate destructor: `private unsafe void ~KerningHelper()`.

Comment: In CLI/C++ the !KerningHelper would symbolise a `finalizer` rather than a `destructor` perhaps it's something to do with that? Have a look here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CLI#Finalizers_and_automatic_variables

Comment: It isn't valid C# either way, so I'm guessing some IL representation that is then translated back slightly wrong.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth: I did check writing my own class with that and came to the same conclusion. I'm interested in what it was originally / what it's for / what the original syntax is. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the comments stated, the exclamation mark is the C++/CLI marker for a finalizer method. Unlike traditional C++ destructors (~) that are called when you explicitly dispose of an object, finalizers are called by the garbage collector thread. You can see the official details [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177197%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

I would expect ILSpy to translate the `!KerningHelper()` to `~KerningHelper()`, since C++/CLI finalizer is equivalent to C#'s destructor - it's a non-deterministic method that occurs when the GC gets to it, unlike C++/CLI's explicit ~destructor, which is called when you call `delete` or an explicit Dispose call is made.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, what confused me is that the `KerningHelper` had a destructor too, so I guess ILSpy uses `!` as it's different to a destructor. If you know of a use for a finalizer I'd appreciate it as in the class I've found I think `dispose` should get called anyway so I don't understand its use (i.e. when would a finalizer be used instead of/as well as a destructor?).